# Progress Bar not showing while performing HTTP request on button click

Tags: android, progress-bar, executorservice

I am executing an `HTTP request` on button click and I am implementing the request procedure using an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). I have a `ProgressBar` that is supposed to start spinning while the request is being processed. Now that dose not happen, I see no spinning circle.
Here is button click code:

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
            setFieldDetails();
            if(// Some condition)
                // Some Action
            else if(// Some condition)
                // Some action
            else if(// Some condition)
                //Some Action
            else {
                runOnUiThread(() -> progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE));
                signUpAction = signUpAction.createSignUpAction();
                Future<Integer> signUpResponse = executorService.submit(signUpAction);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                try {
                    if(signUpResponse.get() == 200){
                        executorService.shutdown();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else
                        // Do something irrelevant 
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    // Manage Exceptions
                }
            }
        });
```

**Why is the `ProgressBar` not showing up?**
**How to make it show up?**
I can do it with the help of [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) but I do not want to use it because of implementation concerns. I want to stick to using [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)
I have also tried running it without `runOnUiThread(Runnable r)` but same result.
Here is my class for sending request:

```
public class PostDataClass {
    private HashMap<String,String> dataMap;
    private final String url;
    private final String charset;
    private int responseCode;

    public PostDataClass(String[] params, String[] values, String url) throws IOException {
        this.url = url;
        this.charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();
        this.dataMap = new HashMap<>();
        if(params.length == values.length){
            for(int i = 0 ; i < params.length ; i++) this.dataMap.put(params[i],values[i]);
        }else throw new NullPointerException("Values and params count aren't equal");
        makePostRequest();
    }

    @NonNull
    private String makeQuery() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        ArrayList<String> keySet = new ArrayList<>(this.dataMap.keySet());
        ArrayList<String> valuesSet = new ArrayList<>(this.dataMap.values());
        for(int i = 0 ; i < valuesSet.size() ; i++) s.append(keySet.get(i)).append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode(valuesSet.get(i),this.charset)).append("&");
        return s.toString();
    }

    private void makePostRequest() throws IOException {
        URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(this.url).openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", this.charset);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + this.charset);

        try(OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream()){
            outputStream.write(makeQuery().getBytes(this.charset));
            urlConnection.connect();
            this.responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection)urlConnection).getResponseCode();
        }
    }

    public int getResponseCode(){
        return this.responseCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: show the code of service

Comment: @ZaidMirza What exactly do you mean by service? My Http request sending code?

Comment: yes executorService.submit

Answer (score 0):

Put the progressbar statement at the top before your last conditional block.

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
            setFieldDetails();
            runOnUiThread(() -> progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE));

            if(// Some condition)
                // Some Action
            else if(// Some condition)
                // Some action
            else if(// Some condition)
                //Some Action
            else {

                signUpAction = signUpAction.createSignUpAction();
                Future<Integer> signUpResponse = executorService.submit(signUpAction);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                try {
                    if(signUpResponse.get() == 200){
                        executorService.shutdown();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else
                        // Do something irrelevant 
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    // Manage Exceptions
                }
            }
        });
```